# How to filter Firestore Server Timestamp when I get the data from DatePicker?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Assume that I get the DatePicker result is

D/date: Tue Oct 12 16:20:27 GMT+08:00 2021

D/time: Timestamp(seconds=1634026827, nanoseconds=550000000)

```
val datePicker = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            val timeStamp = Timestamp(calendar.time)
            val date = calendar.time

            Log.d("date", "$date")
            Log.d("time", "${timeStamp}")

            Log.d("time", "${date}")
            Firestore().filterOrderList(this, recyclerView, date)
        }

        val style = AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
        DatePickerDialog(
            requireContext(),
            style,
            datePicker,
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
```

And my filter function is

```
    fun filterOrderList(activity: Fragment, recyclerView: RecyclerView, timestamp: Timestamp) {
        mFirestore.collection(Constants.ORDERS)
            .whereEqualTo("date", timestamp)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                Log.d("result", "${result.documents}")
                val orderItem = result.toObjects(UserOrderList::class.java)
                recyclerView.adapter = OrderListItemAdapter(activity, activity.requireContext(), orderItem)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e("error", "$e") }
    }
```

[my Firestore data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUHOv.png)

But I get the result is empty. How can I only filter date like 12 Oct 2021 without GMT+08:00

Comment: What's the value of `timestamp` inside whereEqualTo?

Comment: @AlexMamo The value of timestamp inside is that my Firestore data structure image. The image is given by UTC+8. When I get the timestamp and convert to date is given by GMT+8. But I think that is not affect just only left filter problem.